# Move camera to a gameobjects forward position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

This is going to be hard to explain but I'll give it a shot.
I have a camera set up like this...
[image]

The code for the camera is this...
`transform.position = new Vector3(car.transform.position.x-posX+carPos, car.transform.position.y+posY, car.transform.position.z-posZ) + car.transform.forward * (Mathf.Clamp(speed, 0, 0.70f)*40);`

Which basically equates to get the car x, y and z, displace it a bit above back and left. The `+ car.transform.forward * (Mathf.Clamp(speed, 0, 0.70f)*40);` is saying look ahead of the car by a small amount depending on the speed of the car so when we are stationary the car is in the center of the camera, when the car is travelling fast point the camera slightly ahead of the car. 
The problem I have is that the last part makes the camera snap around when the car is turning quickly. I am hoping I can smooth out the position of the camera to kind of chase the position it needs to track. If you can imagine the existing position as a dot in front of the car, I want the camera to chase that dot smoothly instead of being really snappy.

[Example](https://youtu.be/KSEx_DRy8TI)

So not sure how to go about this. Will I need to get the current position and Lerp to the next frame position? Lerping between one frame a fraction of distance doesn't seem right to me. 
It's just too snappy and I'd rather it be smooth.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`Vector3.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html) for this. To make it work, you'll need to keep track of the camera's (relative) velocity and the camera's offset due to speed between frames.

Altogether, with some parameters you can fine tune to be appropriate this might look like this,:

```
Vector3 camVelocity = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 camSpeedOffset = Vector3.zero;
float cameraSmoothTime = 0.1f;
float maxCameraOffsetVelocity = 1f;

...

Vector3 camSpeedOffsetTarget = car.transform.forward * (Mathf.Clamp(speed, 0, 0.70f)*40);
camSpeedOffset = Vector3.SmoothDamp(camSpeedOffset, camSpeedOffsetTarget, 
        ref camVelocity, cameraSmoothTime, maxCameraOffsetVelocity);

transform.position = new Vector3(
        car.transform.position.x-posX+carPos, 
        car.transform.position.y+posY, 
        car.transform.position.z-posZ) 
      + camSpeedOffset;
```

Comment: Wow `The most common use is for smoothing a follow camera.`. Never heard of this one before but sounds perfect. Thanks!

Comment: God damn dude, that code works 100% perfect. You are a saviour. Endings credits mention for sure <3